# wordpress "rest_upload_no_data, No data provided."

Tags: wordpress, go, request, wordpress-rest-api

I using wordpress api for upload image (png) using this code

```
data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(inFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
createMediaReq.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(strings.NewReader(string(data)))
```

and https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1149443342921375775/1149447070571315240/a.png this png its worked but another png didt worked (with this error : wordpress.Response{status:"400. Bad Request", message:"rest_upload_no_data, Keine Daten bereitgestellt."})
I don't understand why

Comment: add a fmt.Println(err) after readFile to check if there is any error in reading that png. is there any error?

Answer (score -1):

I just delete code and write again and it worked
I changed something

```
createMediaReq, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "", bytes.NewReader(data))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

I create the body first and give it